# True or false statement on maximal solutions $x'+p(t)x=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Determine if the following statement is true or false: if $p,q:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are continuous functions such that $q(t)\geq p(t)$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, and every maximal solution of $x'+p(t)x=0$, satisfies $\lim_{x\to \infty}x(t)= 0$, then every maximal solution of $y'+q(t)y=0$, satisfies $\lim_{x\to \infty}y(t)= 0$.

**My attempt:**
Using $e^{\int_{t_0}^tp(s)ds}$ and $e^{\int_{t_0}^tq(s)ds}$ as integrating factors I can find the solutions $x(t)=Ce^{-\int_{t_0}^tp(s)ds}$ and $y(t)=Ce^{-\int_{t_0}^tq(s)ds}$, choosing $C>0$ then I have $0\leq y(t)\leq x(t)$, and since $x(t)\to 0$ then $y(t)\to 0$, so the statement seems to be true. I'm doing something wrong?